# File download sometimes restart from the beginning when network has changed(AFURLSessionManager)

Tags: objective-c, download, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I'm having trouble with file download. My app is using AFURLSessionManager and make NSURLDownloadSessionTask by (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTaskWithRequest:progress:destination:completionHandler:.

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [[DownloadTask sharedInstance] downloadTaskWithRequest:request 
                                      progress:nil 
                                      destination:nil 
                                      completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, 
                                                       NSURL * _Nullable filePath, 
                                                       NSError * _Nullable error) {
    self.resumeData = error.userInfo[NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData];
}];
```

It works nice usually but sometimes its download starts from the beginning when I change network. LTE->Wifi, Wifi->another Wifi, Wifi->LTE.

I tried to use resumeData but there's no error, so resumeData is nil, just start file download from the start again.

Can anyone give me a hint solve this situation?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is AFURLSessionManager?

Comment: @ElTomato It's part of AFNetworking.

Comment: Is the problem server-specific?  Content-type specific?  Have you tried reusing the previous resumeData blob?  Wait, what do you mean there's no error?  If there's no error, you should have a filePath and a response object.  Are you sure the content didn't cease to exist between retries?  ETag problem?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257103/nsurlsession-cant-get-resume-data-after-calling-cancelbyproducingresumedata for other ideas.

Comment: @dgatwood Thank you for your reply. I thought it was iOS-side issue, but it was server-side issue. Server conforms the five limitation that Apple says server must follow. But something is wrong. We are investigating which one is wrong. Maybe 'Range' header issue.